# How to make an efficient SQL Select in this situation?

Tags: mysql, performance, select, join, multiple-tables

I have a table structure like this in a MySQL database:

```
#data_table
(id) | user_id | (more fields...)

#relations_table
(id) | user_id | user_coach_id | (...)
```

I would like to select all rows in `relation_table` that have a given `user_coach_id` and for each of those all rows in `data_table` that match the `user_id`. Ideally in one query, even more ideally in a way that will make processing of the data not too complicated.

My SQL skills are a bit rusty so I hope someone can help me out or at least point in the right direction.

*(Note: The framework I will be using in this case is the wordpress wpdb class. But I think it's not really relevant.)*

**Edit:** Thank you, I got to work what I have requested, but now I've run into a more complex scenario, so I made a [more specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34171176/5616681) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply put a Join(for an example "*Left Join*")

```
SELECT data_table.id ,data_table.user_id ,data_table.(more_fields...), relations_table.user_id 
FROM data_table
LEFT JOIN relations_table
ON data_table.id =relations_table.user_id 
ORDER BY data_table.id ;
```

For more Reference : [W3Schools SQL Tutorial in Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but good enough for me to figure out the rest. Also http://www.w3fools.com/ But I agree, that it's a good starting point for an overview :-)

Answer (score 1):

"for a given user_coach_id" makes it:

```
DECLARE @User_Coach_Id = 100

SELECT rt.user_id, ...
FROM #data_table dt
INNER JOIN #relations_table rt
ON dt.user_id = rt.user_id
WHERE rt.User_Coach_Id = @User_Coach_Id
```

Comment: mysql chokes on declare statement. However I didn't mention that I'm using MySQL. Sorry.

Comment: @arsylum, ok, so you would just do the same thing except using he MySQL syntax.

Comment: yup thanks. have a +1 for your effort, especially for making me aware of the more readable symbol notation of database names!

Answer (score 1):

Relations_table is a many:many table?  Leave out the id; it is a waste, and slows things down.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

The framework is relevant if it won't let you do what is optimal.