# Only return an ordered subset of the rows from a joined table

Tags: mysql, select, join, subquery

Given a structure like this in a MySQL database

```
#data_table
(id) | user_id | time | (...)

#relations_table
(id) | user_id | user_coach_id | (...)
```

we can select all `data_table` rows belonging to a certain `user_coach_id` (let's say 1) with

```
SELECT rel.`user_coach_id`, dat.*
FROM `relations_table` rel
LEFT JOIN `data_table` dat ON rel.`uid` = dat.`uid`
WHERE rel.`user_coach_id` = 1
ORDER BY val.`time` DESC
```

returning something like

```
| user_coach_id | id | user_id | time | data1 | data2 | ...
|             1 |  9 |       4 |   15 |   foo |   bar | ...
|             1 |  7 |       3 |   12 |   oof |   rab | ...
|             1 |  6 |       4 |   11 |   ofo |   abr | ...
|             1 |  4 |       4 |    5 |   foo |   bra | ...
```

*(And so on. Of course time are not integers in reality but to keep it simple.)*

But now I would like to query (ideally) only up to an arbitrary number of rows from `data_table` per distinct `user_id` but still have those ordered (i.e. newest first). Is that even possible?

I know I can use `GROUP BY user_id` to only return 1 row per user, but then the ordering doesn't work and it seems kind of unpredictable which row will be in the result. I guess it's doable with a subquery, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of rows in each GROUP is complicated.  It is probably best done with an @variable to count, plus an outer query to throw out the rows beyond the limit.

My blog on [*Groupwise Max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) gives some hints of how to do such.